# Matching key and values in python

Tags: python, key

im having trouble producing output
i want to go from here

```
<keys>  -  <values>
<x>     -  <values 1>
<x>     -  <values 2>
<x>     -  <values 3>
<y>     -  <values 1>
<y>     -  <values 2>
<y>     -  <values 3>
```

to here

```
<keys>  -  <values>
<x>     -  <values 1><values 2><values 3>
<y>     -  <values 1><values 2><values 3>
```

and here are my codes

```
import sys

def emit(x, y):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(x,y))

val_x= ''
val_y = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    x, y = line.split('\t', 1)
    if val_x== x:
        val_y =val_x.join(y) #error flagged this line
    else:
        if val_x:
            emit(val_x, val_y)
        val_x= x
        val_y = y

if val_x:
        emit(val_x, val_y)
```

the data was from a csv file, this part only contains everything after the data was uploaded

Comment: you can read more info about `join()` function, follow [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think below code maybe works:

```
import sys

def emit(x, y):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(x,y))

key_x = None
val_y = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    x, y = line.split('\t', 1)
    if key_x == None:
        key_x = x

    if key_x != x:
        emit(key_x, ' '.join(val_y))
        key_x = x
        val_y = []

    val_y.append(y)

if key_x:
    emit(key_x, ' '.join(val_y))
```